# Query not fetching correct details

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi, I am trying to learn android. I wrote a query to fetch details except the first selected row. But it's not working? Anything wrong from my side?

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT *  FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS +" WHERE "+ ITEMFOLDER_ID +"=?"+"AND id NOT IN (SELECT id from itemTable  WHERE idFolder =? LIMIT 0,1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

- There is no guaranteed order unless you specifiy one; the subquery can return any random record that matches. Add an `ORDER BY` clause, or use something like `... (SELECT min(id) FROM itemTable WHERE idFolder=?)`.
- You have two parameters; ensure that both are set.

And some further remarks:

- If you're using the `TABLE_ITEMS` and `ITEMFOLDER_ID` symbols, you should probably use them in the subquery, too.
- The subquery returns no more than one record, so instead of `IN`, you could write the condition a little more efficiently as `... AND id != (SELECT ...)`.